How to remove unexpected shadow on ElevatedCard in Jetpack Compose?
I have an ElevatedCard in my app and it looks really good:

and its code is here:
ElevatedCard(
    content = {
        Text(
            fontSize = 20.sp,
            text = "All cars",
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 12.dp)
        )
    },
    onClick = {

    },
    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 4.dp)
)

However, when I add more composables/views, an icon button and a text, there appear unexpected shadows at the corners while the shadow on sides and up and below almost disappear (I don't know how to describe it better):

and when it gets expanded:

Here is the code:
var expanded by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

ElevatedCard(
    content = {
        Row(
            content = {
                Text(
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    text = "All cars",
                    modifier = Modifier.weight(weight = 1f).padding(start = 6.dp)
                )

                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        expanded = !expanded
                    },
                    checked = expanded,
                    icon = R.drawable.ic_chevron,
                    contentDescription = R.string.expand,
                    tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
                )
            },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 4.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        )

        ScaleVisible(
            content = {
                Text(
                    fontSize = 14.sp,
                    color = Color.DarkGray,
                    text = "All cars from the latest catalog.",
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(bottom = 4.dp)
                )
            },
            visible = expanded,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 10.dp)
        )
    },
    onClick = {
        expanded = !expanded
    },
    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 4.dp).animateContentSize()
)

As you can see there changes something and makes the ElevatedCard work incorrectly.
I also played a lot with paddings around the card and within its content, but no changes.
What I do wrong?
BTW, here the rest of the code of custom I use in my app:
@Composable
fun ScaleVisible(
    visible: Boolean,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    duration: Int = AnimationConstants.DefaultDurationMillis,
    content: @Composable AnimatedVisibilityScope.() -> Unit
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        content = content,
        visible = visible,
        modifier = modifier,
        enter = scaleIn(tween(duration)),
        exit = scaleOut(tween(duration))
    )
}

@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class, ExperimentalAnimationGraphicsApi::class)
fun Icon(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    iconSize: Dp = 30.dp,
    @DrawableRes icon: Int,
    visible: Boolean = true,
    checked: Boolean? = null,
    @StringRes contentDescription: Int,
    tint: Color = LocalContentColor.current,
) {
    ScaleVisible(
        content = {
            TooltipBox(
                tooltip = {
                    PlainTooltip(
                        contentColor = Color.White,
                        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.secondary
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
                            text = stringResource(id = contentDescription)
                        )
                    }
                },
                content = {
                    Icon(
                        tint = tint,
                        painter = if (checked != null)
                            rememberAnimatedVectorPainter(
                                atEnd = checked,
                                animatedImageVector = AnimatedImageVector.animatedVectorResource(id = icon)
                            )
                        else
                            painterResource(id = icon),
                        modifier = Modifier.size(size = iconSize),
                        contentDescription = onString(id = contentDescription)
                    )
                },
                state = rememberTooltipState(),
                positionProvider = TooltipDefaults.rememberPlainTooltipPositionProvider()
            )
        },
        visible = visible,
        modifier = modifier
    )
}

@Composable
fun IconButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    iconSize: Dp = 30.dp,
    @DrawableRes icon: Int,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    visible: Boolean = true,
    checked: Boolean? = null,
    @StringRes contentDescription: Int,
    tint: Color = LocalContentColor.current,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    ScaleVisible(
        content = {
            IconButton(
                content = {
                    val color = if (enabled)
                        tint
                    else
                        Color.LightGray
                    Icon(
                        icon = icon,
                        tint = color,
                        checked = checked,
                        iconSize = iconSize,
                        contentDescription = contentDescription
                    )
                },
                onClick = onClick,
                enabled = enabled
            )
        },
        visible = visible,
        modifier = modifier
    )
}


Please [edit] your question and provide ScaleVisible if it is necessary to reproduce the problem, otherwise please remove it. Also, please provide IconButton. Judging from the parameters it doesn't seem to be the one from the standard compopsables.

Also, does the problem still occur when you remove animateContentSize?

@Leviathan thank you for your response. I edited the question and provided the missing part of code. BTW, I just removed the animateContentSize and it loos good, so the problem gone, but there is no animation when size of the card changes. Nevertheless, thank you very much, at least I have a good looking card.
